# Implementing a clear button for a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

I'm implementing a clear button for a JFrame which consists of four JPanels. Each JPanel has several text fields, radio buttons and checkboxes.

When the forms loads "clear" buttons should be disabled. It should be only enabled when the user entered some value to any of those fields in any panel.

I tried by adding a KeyListener to the panels. But It does not get the events properly. Do I have to register KeyListener for all the UI components? Any other good method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For making changes you can add `ItemListener` to your `JCheckBox` and `JRadioButtons` and for `JTextField` you can add `CaretListener`.

This small program might help you :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.CaretListener;
import javax.swing.event.CaretEvent;

public class StateChangedEventClass extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel contentPane, panel1, panel2;
    private JButton clearButton;
    private ItemListener itemChangeAction;
    private CaretListener caretAction;

    public StateChangedEventClass()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        clearButton = new JButton("CLEAR");
        clearButton.setEnabled(false);

        itemChangeAction = new ItemListener()
        {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ce)
            {
                clearButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        };

        caretAction = new CaretListener()
        {
            public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent ce)
            {
                clearButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        };

        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2  , 2));
        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("USERNAME : ", JLabel.CENTER);
        JTextField userField = new JTextField(10);
        userField.addCaretListener(caretAction);
        JLabel passLabel = new JLabel("PASSWORD : " + JLabel.CENTER);
        JTextField passField = new JTextField(10);
        passField.addCaretListener(caretAction);
        panel1.add(userLabel);
        panel1.add(userField);
        panel1.add(passLabel);
        panel1.add(passField);
        contentPane.add(panel1);

        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        JRadioButton maleButton = new JRadioButton("MALE", false);
        maleButton.addItemListener(itemChangeAction);
        JRadioButton femaleButton = new JRadioButton("FEMALE", false);
        femaleButton.addItemListener(itemChangeAction);
        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        bg.add(maleButton);
        bg.add(femaleButton);
        panel2.add(maleButton);
        panel2.add(femaleButton);
        contentPane.add(panel2);

        add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(clearButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent ce)
    {
        clearButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new StateChangedEventClass();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @pavithraCS : Your Welcome and Keep Smiling :-)

Answer (score 4):

[KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) isn't designated for [Listening](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) a `Keyboards` events in the Swing GUI, for Swing is there [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: But not sure, seems like KeyListeners in this case will be more appropriate, since it won't be a good idea to bind all 26 keys for alphabets and 10 for digits on the keyboard to check which key the user pressed on the JTextField. Hope I am not wrong :-)

Comment: someone of Swing Gurus here calculating number of chars required for good `KeyListener` and `KeyBinding`s, there isn't diametral difference by counting chars in the code, back to `KeyBindings` only to call `JButton#doClick()` from `KeyBinding`s Action [JButton#doClick()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

You must adding ActionListeners to your JTextFields, after this check text value in text fields, for example:

```
jButton.setEnabled(!jTextField.getText().equals(""));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.But there are many textfields in the form. I want to find a simple solution.

Comment: you can define boolean flag, for example:
boolean flag = !jTextField1.getText().equals("") || ... || !jTextFieldN.getText().equals("");

jButton.setEnabled(flag);

Answer (score 1):

> It should be only enabled when the user entered some value to any of
>   those fields in any panel.

So you should implement `KeyListener` interface for all these fields. Upon detecting typing action of the user you should enable the button.

```
jButton.setEnabled(true);
```

> Do I have to register KeyListener for all the UI components?

Of course no. Write a class which extends JTextField and implements KeyListener. Derive your objects (all text fields) from this class. If you implement what you should do upon key strokes, all these objects will obey your rule.